# Defining an array as non empty in json schema

Tags: arrays, json

Is there any way to define an array as non empty in JSON schema?

Comment: Are you referring to json-schema.org?

Answer (score 17):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#length), you can define the minimum amount of items with `"minItems": 1`:

```json
{
    "id": "http://some.site.somewhere/entry-schema#",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "schema for an fstab entry",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "options": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1, // -> array must not be empty
            "items": { "type": "string" },
            "uniqueItems": true
        },
        "readonly": { "type": "boolean" }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem here, depending on what the OP means by "non empty", is that `[,]` is considered as non empty by JavaScript, having 1 element (yes, length 1 and not 2) set to `undefined`. As a consequence, this array matches the `"minItems": 1` schema, behaviour that could be unwanted...

Comment: @dgiugg okay yes, you're right. But since this is only a schema I think this is the best solution. Or do you have a better solution? :)

Comment: Well, I wish I had! Unfortunately json-schema does not recognize `undefined` as a primitive type, so you can't event use `"items": {"not": {"type": "undefined"}}` :(

Comment: @dgiugg but if json-schema would recognize it, a list like `["x", "y", undefined, 1]` wouldn't match the schema (possibly you could get something like this from an API)  - am I wrong?

Comment: Haha damn you are right! We would need a sort of "notAll" (equivalent to "atLeastOne") option for array items. Don't know if it exists.